# Selenium web driver hangs while trying to test a Flask app

Tags: python, selenium, flask, testing

I am trying to write an automated test for my web app and I encountering a weird issue;

when trying to call `driver.get('https://my-local-app-url:port')` Chrome just hangs and never really opens the URL. However, when using the `driver.get()` on Google.com it works just fine.

This is how I have everything set up:

The "test":

```
class TestApp:
def test_app(self, chrome_browser, app):
    chrome_browser.get('https://google.com') << this line execute just fine
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
    chrome_browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/') << this one does not execute
```

conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def chrome_browser():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    return browser

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

The create_app function:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    return app
```

*Outside the test, the function create_app is working just fine and returning a Flask object.
*My Chrome driver and chrome version are 86.04240.22.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that `app.run()` call is blocking and all code after that line will be executed only after flask server stops. You could start flask in a separate thread with some restrictions using `app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)`, but more logical approach would be implementing selenium integration tests in separate classes and start them as a separate processes.

Comment: Thank you! What should I do if I want to the Flask server running only once executing the tests? Does it make sense to call app.run() in the conftest file?

Comment: You can find quite detailed tutorial for setting up flask and selenium e.g. [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-flask-app-with-selenium-webdriver-part-1).

Comment: Thank you, Alexandra.
Unfortunately, it is not working, I posted about the issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305197/getting-a-cant-pickle-local-object-liveservertestcase-error-when-trying-to

If you have any ideas how to overcome this it will be great, I could not find anything online.